# Data Structures used in Clustered and Non-Clustered Index

Tags: sql, database, indexing, relational-database, database-indexes

I read about Clustered and Non-Clustered Index and concluded that , we use Hashing for Clustered Index and B+ tree (or B tree) for Non-Clustered Index. Is my conclusion right? If not, then what is the difference between these two at data structure level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This answer was written when the question seemed to be focused on MySQL.*

Since you have tagged the question [mysql], we should limit the discussion to what is possible with *that* RDBMS.

The one "Engine" you should mostly be using these days is InnoDB.  It has primarily B+Tree indexes.  (It also has `FULLTEXT` and `SPATIAL`, but I won't get into them.)  It does *not* have "Hash".

The `PRIMARY KEY` is a clustered B+Tree.  All the data is ordered by the PK and stored into that one B+Tree.  The PK can only be clustered and can only be BTree.  The PK is also Unique (in MySQL).

Secondary keys are also B+Trees.  They contain the column(s) of the secondary  index.  At the leaf nodes is the column(s) of the primary key.  A "point query" via a secondary index requires drilling down the secondary BTree, then drilling down the Primary key.  Secondary keys cannot be "clustered".

For general purpose use, a BTree is the best.  A Hash is rarely any better.  A Hash is useless for range scans, where as a BTree, especially a B+Tree, is excellent for such.

Hashes are terrible when the index is bigger than can be cached in RAM.  Typically the 'next' key you want to access is not adjacent to the last one you touched, so there is a good chance of needing I/O.

Comment: Basically it was an interview question and I was asked where is hashing and B tree used in clustered and non-clustered index. What should I reply for that ?

Comment: It depends.  If the position is for MySQL only, the question is nonsense, and your best answer might be to point out (politely) that they know less about MySQL than you do.  If the position might involve other engines (MSSql, Oracle, Postgres, etc), then I did not give you the answer they are looking for -- namely that you understand the concepts of "clustered index", "hash" vs "BTree" (and maybe "B+Tree"), "primary" vs "secondary", "unique", etc.  Look up those on Wikipedia.  Those terms are _mostly_ orthogonal.

Comment: Thanks for the response , but will you please tell the solution realted to it for general case (including MSSql, Oracle, Postgres, etc)

Comment: Suggest you change the tags to avoid the apparent MySQL focus, then hope others will jump in.  (I don't have sufficient breadth or currency of info to give you an up-to-the-decade answer.)

Answer (score 0):

In simple words we can explain like below.

Both the Clustered and non-clustered index follows b-tree structure,

```
for clustered index leaf node of the b-tree structure contains the Actual data.
for non clustered index leaf node of the b-tree structure points the address of the actual data.
```

Comment: So when do we use hashing ?

Comment: Hashing will generate shorter fixed length keys against strings of larger size.. If you wanted to know more about hashing read the article over the following link http://mobile.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/getting-started-with-hashing-in-sql-server.html

Comment: @UnnikrishnanR - That link is talks about MSSql, not MySQL.